# SQL Query UNION with inner Join / left join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

im stuck with some "simple" sql query.
I want to query all DB's and get all sql-users back.

first i used the sp_foreachdb, but than read its not supported and also the output is not the best for further handling...

```
DECLARE @command varchar(1000)
SELECT @command = 'USE [?]
IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4
SELECT ''?'' as DBName, * FROM sysusers AS SU
Left Join sys.server_principals AS SP
ON SU.sid = SP.sid
WHERE SP.type = ''S''
ORDER BY SU.name'
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Now i get bit further with nested queries and UNION.
But now i get all users and not only the sql users (not system-users)

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL;

SELECT  @Sql = COALESCE(@Sql + ' UNION ALL ' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), '' ) + 'SELECT ''' + DB.[name] + ''' AS dbname, SU.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS AS Username 
FROM ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + '.sys.sysusers AS SU'
--INNER Join sys.server_principals AS SP'
--ON SU.sid = SP.sid
--WHERE SP.type = ''S''
--ORDER BY SU.name'

FROM    master.sys.databases as DB
WHERE   [database_id] > 4 AND [state] = 0;

SET @Sql = ' ' + @Sql;

--PRINT @Sql;
EXECUTE ( @Sql )
```

As soon as i add the commented lines back, there is an error with the "next to union statement"...

Can anyone show me how to correct use a "for each database" query? :)

Thx alot.

Comment: `select from ... join ... where ... order by ...`, only one FROM and one WHERE per SELECT.

Comment: You have `order by` in the first part of the query (pre-union) and you should only have `order by` at the very end of the query (after all the unions, joins, etc)...

Comment: Thx. Now it works.... just a simple "copy paste" error from the last test and this keeps me up all day long -.-